# Injective hulls of quotient rings $R/p$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be integral domain and $p \neq 0$ a prime ideal.
It's well known that in category of $R/p$ modules the *injective
hull* of $R/p$ is $K=\operatorname{Frac}(R/p)$.
Is there a successful theory known treating injective
hull of $R/p$ considered as $R$-module? If $R= \mathbb{Z}$
then it is known that the inj hull of $\mathbb{Z}/p$
as $\mathbb{Z}$-modukle is
$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])/\mathbb{Z}$.
Is there any fruitful theory known classifying the structure of
injective hulls known going
beyong this 'baby' example $\mathbb{Z}/p$? What if we impose additional restrictive assumtions on $R$ like being local, regular or factorial etc? This is an exact copy of [same mse question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4046476/injective-hulls-of-quotient-rings-r-p) I asked a week ago.

Comment: If $p$ is maximal, $R/p$ is Artinian and its injective hull as $R$-module is the same as its injective hull as $R_p$-module or equivalently $\widehat{R_p}$, and this is the Matlis dual of $\widehat{R_p}$ as $\widehat{R_p}$-module.

Comment: do you know where a proof of this result can be found?

Comment: I'm not aware of a reference. I think this follows from basic properties of Matlis duality.

Comment: For noetherian rings there is the paper of Matlis from 1958.

Comment: Chapters 2, 3 of Hochster's Local Cohomology are one good reference for this stuff.